# How to prove that $x\leq f(x)$ if f order isomorphic?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let X is a well ordered set and $f:X\to f(X)=Y\subseteq X$ is order isomorphic. For any $x\in X$
 prove that $$x\leq f(x)$$

since X is well ordered, {x,f(x)}$\subseteq$X and $x\leq f(x) $ or $f(x)\leq x$.  Assume $f(x)<x$ . since f is order isomorphic  $f(x)<x \Rightarrow f^{-1}(f(x))<f^{-1}(x)$ so $x<f^{-1}(x)$

edit : since $B\subseteq X$ B has a minimum element "a". from definition of B $f(a)<a$ .and  $f(f(a))<f(a)$ so f(a) is in B. since $f(a) <a$ and $f(a)\in B$ this conflicts "a" is the minumum element of B

Comment: Let $B = \{ x\in X : f(x) < x\}$. If $B\neq\varnothing$, since $X$ is well-ordered ...

Comment: How can you compare $x$ with $f(x)$? Isn't $x$ in $X$ and $f(x)$ in $Y$?

Comment: @user99680 the post says $Y\subseteq X$ :)

Comment: @rschwieb: So one is supposed to actually carefully read the post before commenting :) ?

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks. in this question well ordering is a must?

Comment: There may be other properties that imply the conclusion, but something beyond a mere total order is required, looking at $f\colon\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z};\; k \mapsto k-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Suppose that $A=\{x\in X\mid f(x)<x\}$ is non-empty, then it has a minimal element $a$, now use the fact that $f$ is injective and order preserving to conclude that $f(x)\in A$, and derive a contradiction.