# A question regarding: $Y\subseteq X$, and $f:X\cong Y$. Then for all $x\in X$, $x\leq f(x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

This is Th. 1.7.2 in Devlin's "Joy of Sets."

> > Let $(X,\leq)$ be a well-ordered set, $Y\subseteq X$, and $f:X\cong Y$. Then for all $x\in X$, $x\leq f(x)$.

Here, the author's notation $f:X\cong Y$ denotes an order isomorphism.

I am wondering how there could be an order isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$ unless $Y=X$

Also what is the intuition whereby $x$ would be less than $f(x)$.

(I just saw this question [How to prove that $x\leq f(x)$ if f order isomorphic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822253/how-to-prove-that-x-leq-fx-if-f-order-isomorphic?rq=1), but it's not exactly my question.)

Thanks

Comment: Suppose $X$ is the set of all positive integers with the usual ordering, $Y$ is the set of all even positive integers, and $f(x)=2x$ for $x\in X.$ Then $X$ is well-ordered and $f:X\to Y$ is an order isomorphism, but $Y$ is a proper subset of $X.$

Comment: @bof Thanks, you know if you care to post your comment, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: We can have $x=f(x)$ for some $x$ and also $y<f(y)$ for some $y.$ E.g. $X=\Bbb N $  and $ f(x)=x$ for $x<10$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x\geq 10.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A = \{x \in X: x > f(x) \}$. If $A$ were non-empty, it would have a minimum $a_0$ (we are in a well-order). But then $a_0 \in A$ means $a_0 > f(a_0)$ and applying $f$ to both sides gives $f(a_0) > f(f(a_0)$, as $f$ preserves order strictly. This means that $f(a_0) \in A$ too and $f(a_0) < a_0$, contradicting  $a_0$'s minimality. So $A$ is empty, and so we are done: for all $x$: $x \le f(x)$.

It's very possible that $X$ is isomorphic to a subset $Y$: $X = \mathbb{N}$ is order isomorphic to $2\mathbb{N}$ under the obvious map. And indeed $n \le 2n$ for all $n$, as promised.